# Dont want to Clear text box while clicking add button

Tags: javascript, html

i have one requirements for adding text box while clicking button.
When i am clicking add button new text box will be created But previousely entered data in text box will be cleared.I dont want to clear the data in text box while clicking add button.
How i can resolve this problem?

**html**

```
<tr id="div"></tr>
<tr> 
 <td> 
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-info" onclick="generateRow();">Add</button>
 </td>
</tr>
```

**JS**

```
function generateRow() {
   var d=document.getElementById("div");
   d.innerHTML+=" <input class='form-control' type='text' required autofocus name='year'/>  ";
}
```

Comment: `<tr   id="div">` Um… Ceci n'est pas une pipe.?

Comment: @bjb568 i hav to paass uniuqe id name?

Comment: Yes, but my point is that you were calling "tr" "div"…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function generateRow() {
    var i=0,j=0;

    var d=document.getElementById("div"),input,value;
    //var m=document.getElementById("div");
    var x=new Array(50);
    while (i!=d.childNodes.length/2)
    {
    if (input = d.children[i]) {// If there's an input...
        x[i]=input.value; // ...get the value
    }


    //d.children[i].value = value;
    i++;
    }
    d.innerHTML += "<input class='form-control' type='text' required autofocus name='year'/> ";
  //  m.innerHTML += "<td><input  type='button' required autofocus name='year' value='Remove'/> </td>";

    while(j!=i)
        {
    d.children[j].value = x[j];
        j++;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use something like this in javascript

```
function generateRow() {
    var child="<input class='form-control' type='text' required autofocus name='year'/>"; 
    document.getElementById("div").appendChild(child);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use jquery `.append()` to add div to the existing content

Answer (score 1):

try this using pure javascript

```
function generateRow() {
    var d=document.getElementById("div");
    var f = document.createElement("input");
    f.name="year";
    d.appendChild(f);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different answer using jQuery. Might be useful for future users

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script  type="text/javascript">
        function generateRow() {
            $("#div").append("<input type='text' name='year'/><br/>");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <div id="div">
            <!-- Buttons Go Here -->
        </div>
        <button type="button" onclick="generateRow();">Add</button>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

## [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gXf9y/)